# Design time instantiation issues when accessing xml file using XDocument.Load

Tags: windows-store-apps, designer

In my windows store app using the Visual Studio 2012 designer I want to be able to load some model objects for the designer.  I've done this plenty of times before where I supply a xaml file using the ms-appx:/// uri without error.  However, for this project I need to be able to instantiate a class and have it convert raw xml of a different format into my model objects.

I'm using the following xaml to instantiate my class for the designer:

```
d:DataContext="{Binding Source={d:DesignInstance Type=model:Walkthroughs, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"
```

In my Walkthroughs class had code that did this initially:

```
public Walkthroughs()
{
        if (Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
            AppDataLoader.LoadWalkthroughs(this, XDocument.Load("ms-appx:///SampleData/walkthroughs.xml"));
}
```

I first ran into an issue where the XDocument.Load did not understand the ms-appx:/// uri so I modified my code to something very simplistic:

```
AppDataLoader.LoadWalkthroughs(this, XDocument.Load(@"C:\walkthroughs.xml"));
```

Now I get access to path '' is denied.

I've tried several directories as well to no avail.  I'm even running Visual Studio as an Administrator. If I remove the prefix altogether I get the following error:

```
Could not find file 'C:\Users\{me}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Designer\ShadowCache\omxyijbu.m4y\yofsmg1x.avh\walkthroughs.xml'.
```

Has anyone been able to load files from the file system when the designer instantiates objects?

Thanks,
-jeff

Answer (score 0):

`XDocument.Load(string uri)` seems to have problems with loading Project resources from `ms-appx:/`

Regarding your second approach: Direct access to "C:" is not permitted. Ther is only a handful of  [special folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx) that you can access. Check out my workaround for this (my xml file is within the `Assets` folder of my project:

```
var storageFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
storageFolder = await storageFolder.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
var xmlFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("data.xml");
var stream = await xmlFile.OpenReadAsync();           
var rdr = new StreamReader(stream.AsStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")); //needed if you have "ä,ß..." in your xml file
var doc = XDocument.Load(rdr);
```